# OpenLayers 5: Multiple map viewports when multiple maps are defined with same target

Tags: node.js, webpack, openlayers

OpenLayers 5.3

**Update: Please see my answer below. I think this is a red-herring question not at all related to OpenLayers**

I encountered some unexpected behavior when I defined ***but did not import*** a second map using the same target div.

Unexpectedly, within the 'map' div, the viewport was duplicated and the second map appeared, even  though I did not import the second map into my index.js:

**maps.js**

```
import {Map} from 'ol';

export var map0 = new Map({
  layers: some_layers,
  view: some_view,
  target: 'map'
});

export var map1 = new Map({
  layers: other_layers,
  view: someother_view,
  target: 'map'
});
```

**index.js**

```
import {map0 as map} from maps;
// note that map1 is NOT imported
```

**Expected behavior:**
Because  I only imported a single map in index.js, I expected that I would only have a single map viewport in

```
<div id='map'>
```

and that map1, being NOT imported, would NOT be included.

**Actual behavior:**
Within the map div, there were two viewports, one containing map0 and one containing map1.

**Work-around**
In maps.js, omit the 'target' parameter, and then, in index.js:

```
map.setTarget('map')
```

Is this a bug, or expected behavior, or does it reflect a lack of understanding on my part of the behavior of exports and imports?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was not at all an OpenLayers issue.

Furthermore, I believe my question didn't even touch on the underlying issue.

I think this is a webpack-related issue.

I think I need to better understand the concept of 'TreeShaking' and use of the sideEffects parameter in webpack.config.

Though I haven't yet tried this, I think that learning from the link below should help me resolve the issue:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

A quote from the above is directly responsive to my original question:

> Note that we did not import the square method from the src/math.js
>   module. That function is what's known as "dead code", meaning an
>   unused export that should be dropped.

Thus, even though the export is 'unused' it still ends up in the webpack bundle, hence, in the case here, it did add the second map to the same div, as experienced.

I will update this answer with confirmation when/if I achieve that.

Sorry for the false alarm.